# -6 on a question still low quality flag declined

Tags: discussion, questions, flags, low-quality-posts, declined-flags

[Split an expression to float numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674705/split-an-expression-to-float-numbers)

> I have a string like this `"2/-4+5.7*5*-7.9+3"`
>   I want to split it in an array such that the elements are the absolute value of floating numbers only `[2,4,5.7,5,7.9,3]`

Referring to this can anybody explain why was my low quality flag declined?
It already has -6 downvotes.

See screen shot: <kbd>[image: declined flag message]</kbd>

Comment: Answer correctness or question usefulness != post quality. A well-written post can be utterly wrong and downvoted into oblivion, but it won't be low quality. Using the -6 post score as justification that the post is low quality doesn't fly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The flag appears to be on the question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters He's asking about the question; though that is an important thing to remember.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: right; but the same argument applies to questions too.

Comment: Duplicate of [When is a closeable question also a "very low quality" question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357338/when-is-a-closeable-question-also-a-very-low-quality-question)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

VLQ is used to indicate that a post is not just of low quality, but it is such complete and utter unrecoverable garbage as to require immediate deletion.

Downvotes just indicate that a post is of low quality and is not helpful.

The fact that a post has a number of downvotes doesn't automatically means that immediate deletion is warranted.

Comment: I am not asking about it being deleted.I marked it as `low quality flag`.Why has that been turned down?-6 downvotes!!!!!!!!!1doesnt that speak for itself?

Comment: @vks by flagging it as low quality, you are asking for it to be deleted.

Comment: @vks And I'm telling you that the whole point of the VLQ flag is to *indicate that the post requires immediate deletion*.  That is *why that flag exists*.  If you don't think that the post needs to be immediately cleansed with fire then you shouldn't be flagging it as VLQ.

Comment: Read through all the answers.All were helpful in differentiating the flags and other stuff.Marking your as answer coz of this comment of urs.`VLQ flags are rarely handled by moderators. While this one was, most are handled by the community through the LQP review queue.`.was informative.

Answer (score 8):

Flags like "Very Low Quality" are a request for moderator deletion.  Moderators typically don't delete a post unless it is actively harmful to the site.  Very Low Quality specifically refers to posts that *are not salvageable by editing.*

Use a downvote, a close vote, or one of the close flags instead.  You can also cast a custom moderator flag and explain why you think the post warrants immediate deletion rather than going through the usual close process.

Comment: request for moderator deletion, really? ["As of July 2013, Very Low Quality flags automatically add the flagged post to the Low Quality review queue"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190639/165773),  that is to be dealt with by 2K users, not moderators?

Comment: @gnat: The expected outcome is still deletion, and moderators can still handle such flags.

Comment: that sounds plausible. Consider [edit]ing the answer to clarify that. Per my reading, current wording feels almost in a contradiction with the fact that flags push the post into LQ queue

Comment: @gnat: Don't forget that 10K users are considered "moderators" also.  They're just not diamond moderators.

Comment: I know. [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/): "We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users..."

Answer (score 7):

Only flag posts for VLQ when they cannot be recovered by editing; you are asking for a summary execution of the post denying the OP the chance to recover.

The question may not be *useful*, which is why it is voted down and has received close votes. But that also means the *community is already dealing with it*, and doesn't require moderator intervention or summary deletion.

By flagging as VLQ you are asking for reviewers or a moderator to step in and remove it from the site, because downvoting or closing the post is not enough. Your flag was declined because a moderator did not agree that summary deletion was required.

When you come across a question that shows no effort, please down-vote and/or vote to close. If the post were closed and the OP were to edit the post adding a reasonable show of effort, the post could be reopened and answered. If a moderator had deleted it that path would have been closed.

Comment: VLQ flags are rarely handled by moderators.  While this one was, most are handled by the community through the LQP review queue.

Comment: The OP has shown no efforts or attempts neither he describes his problem completely.

Comment: @vks: then *downvote* and vote to close. This is not a review or moderator task.

Comment: @vks That doesn't mean that the post warrants immediate deletion.  That's certainly a reason to downvote the post, or possibly vote to close it.

Comment: @vks: You need to start listening, partner.  A number of people have already stated that Low Quality flags are *requests for deletions.*  That's not the right course of action here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey got the point .Thanks :)

Comment: "cannot be dealt with by the community" sounds weird, given that ["As of July 2013, Very Low Quality flags automatically add the flagged post to the Low Quality review queue"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190639/165773), likely to be dealt with by... community? @Servy high-five

Comment: @gnat: yeah, I need to edit that part too, evidently. Done.