# When is a closeable question also a "very low quality" question?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close, low-quality-posts

Sometimes, when I see a question that is blatantly off-topic or otherwise unsalvageable and cannot in any reasonable sense be said to be editable into an acceptable on-topic question, I will vote to close the question *and* flag it as Very Low Quality. I'm talking about questions like these:

1. How can I upgrade to Windows 10?
2. How do I partition a flash drive in Ubuntu?
3. Where can I download a spec sheet for my oscilloscope?
4. What's the weather like in Peru?
5. How do I become a programmer?

Almost always, my VLQ flag is marked "helpful", and usually (but not always) the question is also deleted.

Am I doing this right? Are VLQ question flags supposed to be used this way, or are they supposed to be reserved only for the worst of the worst questions written in the speech of Mordor which ought not be uttered? Are there conditions where it would it be appropriate to vote to close a question but where flagging it as VLQ would send the flagger to that dark place where there are only declined flags and gnashing of teeth?

This question has nothing to do with the Low Quality Posts queue (which only handles answers) or the Very Low Quality flag that is used for *answers*.

Perhaps one way to answer the question would be to say under what conditions a VLQ question flag should be *declined* on a question that is obviously closeable, or whether there are conditions where a VLQ flag on a question should be marked *helpful* while an ordinary *close* flag should be *declined* (e.g. because the question, despite being VLQ, shouldn't actually be closed).

Obvious possibilities:

- Closeability and VLQ-ness are the same, identical concept.
- Closeability and VLQ-ness are distinct concepts in theory, but fundamental laws of the universe see to it that a question that is just one, but not the other, cannot possibly exist and so they are equivalent concepts in practice.
- Closeability and VLQ-ness are distinct concepts, but the existence of a question that is one, but not the other, is a rare sight indeed and more the stuff of trivia and lore than daily reality, so treating them as the same is unlikely to produce many, if any, misflags or misvotes and might be an acceptable practice in day-to-day life.
- Closeability and VLQ-ness are distinct/orthogonal concepts that only sometimes coincide.
- VLQ questions are a subset of closeable questions - that is, *all* VLQ questions are closeable, but not all closeable questions are VLQ.
- Closeable questions are a subset of VLQ questions - that is, *all* closeable questions are VLQ, but not all VLQ questions are closeable.

Comment: VLQ === Absolute unarguable garbage. That means that no matter who views the question, they would agree that there is absolutely no value whatsoever contained in the question at all.

Comment: @TinyGiant you and I and everyone that follows Shog knows that VLQ flag can mean whatever you want but the system treats it differently. That definitions is simply invalid. VLQ flags are for throwing a question to the triage queue, that's what they do _now_.

Comment: Can't you at least wait a day before downvoting so we'll know what the weather is like in Peru **today**?

Comment: I don't actually know, but I sure feel like using it when it's delete worthy and I can't vote to delete.

Comment: Is there a reason for featuring this?

Comment: @PasserBy It could be that a lot of users are using this flag for Questions, and they are all getting declined.. ?

Comment: Not so fast: 2. is off-topic for SO but on-topic for [Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com) and possibly also [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/145710/how-do-you-partition-a-usb-thumb-flash-drive). In that case it's not VLQ (on its target site) and you should vote to migrate, not close (if it's a duplicate it can be merged after it's migrated). As to your taxonomy, you seem to be neglecting SE has ~100 sites. 1,4,5 are bad. 3. is probably bad but might belong on [Electronics.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=oscilloscope+%22spec+sheet%22) if mention specific model

Comment: @smci This question was asked on Meta Stack Overflow. All of the questions mentioned here are blatantly off-topic for Stack Overflow, and thus self-evidently "low quality". Neither you nor anyone else should be voting to migrate low quality questions.

Comment: All of them are good questions and they shoud have their place on the site network. (1) belongs probably to the SU, (2) to the askubuntu (but also Unix & Linux SE matches), (3) might be problematic but could be interpreted as "what is the spec sheet for the scope X". Then Electronics SE or Engineering SE is the best match, (4) is too broad, but after giving more focus might match Open Data or Earth Science, (5) has a best match on the Workplace SE (where it would be likely closed as dupe), possibly Academia SE or SoftwareEngineering SE.

Comment: These questions should be migrated and then processed on the target site as they should be.That the debate is on VLQ flagging ( = quick delete) or simply closure, migration is not even mentioned, *it is not even considered*, is one of the top 3 disappointing features of the site network / communities.

Comment: Wait, what’s wrong with writing your questions in the speech of Mordor? I’ve been doing that since forever… did I miss a memo?

Comment: @CodyGray: please don't misrepresent what I said. I very clearly stated 1,4,5 are bad, 3. is probably bad but *might* be on-topic for Electronics.SE if it mentioned specific model and issue, otherwise is "seeking recommendation". 2. however is not necessarily low-quality for Unix.SE, hence I and many others here disagree with your opinion that it's VLQ. If you want to support your viewpoint, please add citations. Are agreed that people should be voting to migrate *ok-quality* questions? Then the discussion comes down to: Should we consider quality of a Q according to its migration target site?

Comment: @smci A question that is blatantly off-topic for the site on which it is asked is "very low quality" by any obvious definition. That you might be able to edit it, migrate it, or whatever else doesn't change that fundamental fact. Migration of questions is *strongly* discouraged in the Stack Exchange model anyway, and regardless, it is a specific type of closure, so it does not change what is being asked here.

Comment: I agree with @peterh-ReinstateMonica, in that an honest (but simple) question deserves (at least) a partial answer.

Answer (score 175):

**The sad truth is, nobody has the foggiest idea what "very low quality" (VLQ) flags on questions are for.** This, of course, means that I can't give you an actual answer to your question or even any clear guidance on what to do.

Flaggers don't know or agree on what the VLQ flag means, and neither do moderators. Personally, I mark VLQ flags on questions "helpful" whenever I can understand why the flagger might consider the question to be unsalvageable. That's the only official guidance that really exists for these flags, and it matches what the summary text says in the dialog. I can't bring myself to decline a VLQ flag on a post that fits the description "very low quality" [to a T](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44266/origin-of-fits-x-to-a-t). Often, I will cast a binding vote to close the question, which will automatically mark all pending VLQ flags as helpful. Quick, easy, and convenient.

Except…totally broken. Moderators aren't really supposed to be your personal question-closing valets, and getting a moderator to come in and single-handedly close a question just because you flagged it VLQ instead of (or in addition to) flagging it as needing to be closed is arguably an abuse of the system. If everyone did this, we'd have ~10k VLQ flags in the queue—just like the close queue does now. Nobody can reasonably process all of those, even with binding votes, and so they'd just build up, clog our tubes, and eventually have to start aging away.

Also, since there is no consensus on what VLQ flags on questions are for, not all moderators handle them in exactly the same way I do. There are several other moderators who will decline VLQ flags unless they feel the entire question needs to be *immediately deleted*. To skip closure and go straight to unconditional moderator-imposed deletion is a pretty high bar (remember, nobody can even *undelete* a post deleted by a moderator, except for other moderators), so pretty much the only VLQ flags that they mark helpful are ones raised on total gibberish. This is perhaps a more sane and scalable approach, adhering a bit closer to [Jeff Atwood's vision for the VLQ flag from back in 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606), but there are still a host of problems with this interpretation. Among them are ambiguity, redundancy, and a need to predict the future.

If VLQ is really just for total gibberish, like a cat walking across a keyboard, then it's unclear [how it is any different from the "rude or abusive" flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035). Cats are not allowed to walk across keyboards on Stack Exchange sites; [this already qualifies as abuse of our resources](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035). Maybe VLQ is supposed to be a "this is abusive, but I don't think it deserves a −100 reputation penalty, so I'm flagging it with this other flag instead" flag, but [I say pish posh to that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCEwr.jpg). If the community has decided that posting utter garbage should result in a −100 point penalty, then that's what should happen. If they don't think so, then the implementation should be changed such that rude/abusive doesn't automatically impose such a penalty. We don't need two flags that mean essentially the same thing and differ only in terms of punishment. Flaggers shouldn't even be deciding punishments *anyway*: that is the sole responsibility of moderators, who have insider knowledge both about the system and the history of the user(s) involved.

Furthermore, using VLQ on questions that are "unlikely to be salvageable through editing" is asking the flagger to predict the future. How are you supposed to accurately predict the likelihood that a question can be salvaged by editing? I've made edits to a fair number of questions that rescued them from the brink of unsalvageability. And [*whose* edits are we talking about here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332546/adopt-a-consistent-policy-on-what-requires-editing-means-in-the-review-queues)? If we include edits from the author, then "debug my code" questions that lack code can always be salvaged by editing in the code. If we exclude original author edits, then those questions are always unsalvageable because there's no possible way that anyone else could edit in the author's code.

Finally, even where the flagger has good chance of correctly predicting the future—*e.g.*, on questions like "How can I upgrade to Windows 10?" and "What's the weather like in Peru?", which are obviously of extremely low quality and cannot possibly be edited into shape to fit our guidelines—the VLQ flag is *still* redundant and pointless, because we have *close* reasons for these questions. When does an obviously off-topic question get to skip closure and go straight for VLQ-imposed deletion? What's the brightline? How would this possibly scale?

Again, [Jeff's interpretation is that VLQ flags are appropriate for questions that we would normally just close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94785), such as "I got this exception: <stack trace>". That's a perfect candidate for the "lacks MCVE" close reason. When do I flag as VLQ, and when do I vote to close? Or do I do both? Why should some questions be handled differently than others? (Ah yes, and that brings us right back to your question. No, I still don't know the answer.)

But, Jeff's guidance aside, *everything else* seems to indicate that the VLQ flag is more of a "requires editing" flag. Plenty of flaggers treat them this way, as does a large subset of Meta guidance. The system certainly seems to treat these flags that way, too, using them to [enqueue posts in Triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage), and automatically dismissing them as "helpful" when a post gets edited (no matter how substantial the edit). (The pointlessness of the Triage queue is a soapbox for another day.) The problem with this is obvious: we don't need a "requires editing" flag. Either *you* (the flagger) should be performing the edit yourself, or if you can't because only the original author could perform the necessary edit, then you should be flagging/voting to close it. There is nobody *else* out there monitoring the LQ queue who is going to be able to edit the question into shape when you (the flagger) can't, and the only "flag" that gets raised for the original asker to take action is the closure flag.

I *suspect* that the VLQ flag is just a historical relic from the time before a "requires closure" flag could be raised by anyone. VLQ was just a flag for <3k reputation users without close-vote privileges to indicate problematic questions. That problem has already been addressed, largely *because* the VLQ flag wasn't serving the purpose effectively.

So, **what really needs to happen is that the VLQ flag on questions needs to be eliminated.** VLQ questions should be dealt with in the normal way, by downvoting, closing, and deleting them. That way, no one is required to predict the future. If, in between the time that the question gets closed and deleted, some brave and all-knowing soul is able to edit the question into shape, then that would save it from its impending deletion. If not, and in the normal case, then bye-bye it goes. [Moderators have wanted to get rid of VLQ flags on questions for a long time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195673/it-shouldn-t-be-possible-to-flag-questions-as-very-low-quality), essentially echoing my sentiments here.

[Shog9 hinted at having a similar view back in 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236537/lets-have-an-explicit-triage-system-for-questions-from-new-users#comment775825_236637):

> So what's interesting here is that the existing LQ review works really well for answers, but is... kinda broken for questions, where it's pretty much just a really inefficient way of prioritizing things in the Close queue - meaning a question might *already* have to go through three different queues before it's done. If the final destination for "hopelessly bad" questions was the close queue, with LQ retooled as a "hopelessly bad" option for *answers alone*, this would save a lot of busywork.

But I'm not convinced this goes far enough. **The VLQ flag on answers shouldn't exist, either, because it is redundant with the "not an answer" (NAA) flag.** Anything that can sensibly be flagged as "very low quality" is also "not an answer". If it's of such low quality that it cannot be salvaged and needs to be deleted, then it isn't an answer to the question by our standards. That includes gibberish, "the answer is over here" (which people often mistakenly and/or confusingly call "link-only"), attempts to comment, and attempts to ask questions. The only thing that might be included in VLQ but excluded from NAA are hopelessly *wrong* answers, but the official guidance already explicitly says not to use VLQ flags to indicate wrong answers and this is one of the canned decline reasons.

In reality, both the VLQ and NAA flags on answers just mean "garbage that needs to be deleted" (aka "unsalvageable"). That's how they are processed by the community and by moderators, so that's what the flag name and text should indicate. There's no need for a distinction, not only because it's confusing and redundant, but also because it wastes everyone's time lawyering about the distinction itself. For answers, VLQ and NAA should be merged into a single flag type. Maybe that flag should continue to be called "not an answer". Maybe it should be called "unsalvageable", or maybe "needs to be deleted". I don't particularly care which one is used, and bikeshedding about the precise choice of language is largely a waste of time. We just need to pick one and make the change. This has been proposed before. In fact, it gets proposed about every 2 years. It's been 2 years since the last time it was proposed, so it's on my to-do list to propose it again. Maybe Team DAG will have some time in-between rolling out Jobs feature notifications and removing the numbers from the review queue drop-down.

Comment: +10 for trenchant analysis and that soupçon of frustrated snark.

Comment: since you mentioned gibberish answers, [consensus seems to be](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342847/839601) that these can be flagged abusive (my understanding is this is to make it easier to stop disruptive behavior without having to wait for moderators)

Comment: Yeah. I linked to the exact same "consensus" as Ryan links to in his answer. Top of paragraph 5: *"If VLQ is really just for total gibberish, like a cat walking across a keyboard, then it's unclear [how it is any different from the "rude or abusive" flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035). Cats are not allowed to walk across keyboards on Stack Exchange sites; [this already qualifies as abuse of our resources](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035)."*

Comment: "Cats are not allowed to walk across keyboards on Stack Exchange sites" +100 I **love** this answer.

Comment: _"If the community has decided that posting utter garbage should result in a −100 point penalty, then that's what should happen."_ It's not like this is something we actually have any control over.

Comment: You seem to be driving at something I've wondered - whether a VLQ question is somehow *between* an ordinary closeable question and a question that is Spam or Rude. E.g. perhaps "How do I upgrade to Windows 10?" might be just closeable, but "OMG hao do i upgrade my COMPUTERS HALP!!!!" might be closeable *and* VLQ. It's unfortunate that something like this is not defined.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: +1 for "trenchant" and "soupçon". (To anyone who wants to comment a +1 my comment for +1'ing a comment that +1'ed the answer: don't, enough is enough.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert +1 for the humility to ask that you not be upvoted for commenting about upvoting an interesting comment.

Comment: The only thing I like about VLQ flags on answers is that if it is link only you can flag as VLQ and if the user edits the answer it automatically handles the flag.  Normally their edit is good enough for it to be no longer flagged (at least in the cases I have done this).  With a NAA flag the queue could see a updated answer that should no longer be deleted and the flag could be declined even though the flagger did the right thing.  That said, merging them would git rid of a lot of other problems so I fine with losing the "feature".

Comment: @NathanOliver All these flag mechanics ought to be documented somewhere...

Comment: I can't say I keep up with meta 100%, but a merge of NAA and VLQ seems to go against the "NAA is only for things that literally cannot answer any question" that I thought was sort of the standard. Has that been changed or are totally irrelevant (but technically answers) answers not good for VLQ flags.

Comment: The bikeshedding: one of the key points of these flag reasons *is their name*.  If there are 3 flag reasons that all lead to the same result but have different names, that can be better UI than one "unified" flag reason, *if* it leads to better guidance for users who don't read meta.  As such, I say we paint the bikeshed "Fundamental problems that can only be fixed by original author editing" (with optional comment box to describe what the original author needs to do), which then links it to the difference (flag is auto-cleared if original author edits the question or answer).

Comment: @NathanOliver I used it the same way as you did, the only problem is that when edited it throws an automatic down vote, so that can be messy if the edit is really good (so I switched back to NAA, trusting bot's to tell me when edited). Just for future reference I will also link Tunaki's FR [Merge the “Not An Answer” and “Very Low Quality” flags into one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318952/merge-the-not-an-answer-and-very-low-quality-flags-into-one)

Comment: @Yakk good luck with that. I once proposed that we gave hints to people when a flag should be used, but [Shog said we were enumerating badness](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276162/add-a-low-quality-posts-button-to-delete-answer-because-it-doesnt-answer-the-qu/276184#comment114491_276184)

Comment: `cast a binding vote to close the question` is it really casting a vote or is it just 'closing'? Mods don't really get "votes" anymore, do they?

Comment: @mbrig: VLQ flags aren't any better for flagging "does not answer *this* question" answers, as they are handled identically by reviewers and mods alike.

Comment: On "rude or abusive", call me narrow-minded, but the definition of "abusive" that I consider for the purposes of handling the flag is "abusive to others", just like the mod message. I never consider "abusive of our resources" - I even go for weeks forgetting that such an interpretation of that flag exists, even though I use verbiage like "X is abuse of the system" all the time.

Comment: @nathantuggy Good point, though it seems a little off that for ex, a jQuery answer to a x86 asm question wouldn't fit a flag whose description is roughly "unsalvageable & might need deletion"

Comment: @mbrig: The handling of that type of answers is pretty messy all around, and every aspect is a new facepalm.

Comment: @NathanOliver That make sense, but should not be necessary. If you flag as NAA, but the post becomes an answer in the meantime, community review will mark the flag as "disputed", rather than declined. The only case where it would be declined is if a moderator looks at it (we can't dispute these flags). That is, unfortunately, a possibility, since the built-in tools don't warn us when an answer has been edited post-flagging. If we don't have a user-script installed that provides such a warning, we might miss it. Still, a declined flag here and there isn't a big deal.

Comment: @mbrig The point is, VLQ aren't for those types of answers, either. I will say that I diverge slightly from some of the other moderators in how I handle NAA flags. Specifically, I evaluate the answer in the context of the question. The "not an answer to *any* question" standard is excessively silly, in my opinion. x86 asm answers to jQuery questions are NAA. Still, the motivation here is that mods cannot be the arbiters of what is a *correct* answer, and that holds equally true for VLQ flags as NAA flags. In the status quo, these flags are processed identically by the community and moderators.

Comment: @Yakk I agree with some of that, specifically the part that the UI should be optimized for the best results. But what you've described there is just a reinvention of the "needs to be closed" flag. NAA and VLQ aren't for that. They are for garbage that needs to be immediately deleted, so *that's* what the flag description should say.

Comment: @TylerH Behind the scenes, it's still a vote, albeit a binding one. Implementation detail, I guess.

Comment: I love the personal religious aspect of this answer. Reminds me of the way I use the "Unclear" close vote by thinking to myself the magic words: "It's unclear to me how anyone could possibly ask such a dumb question." I _never_ use VLQ because to me, "unclear" is a catch-all.

Comment: If a cat strolling across the keyboard is considered "rude or abusive" then I think that term could change. It may be considered an abuse of SO resources but I would interpret "rude or abusive" to be abuse targeted at other users. Anyway, IMO a gibberish post is actually much better than a bad misleading post that, for example, leads to a bad bug or security vulnerability in code

Comment: @Chris except that bad/misleading answers _are_ answers. Gibberish answers are not. One of the major reasons as to why a gibberish answer should be flagged as abuse (and one of the reasons BoltClock doesn't see these all to often) is that six abuse flags will instantly delete the post, whereas you can flag an answer thousands and it will be the same as if it had been flagged once

Comment: "There is nobody else out there monitoring the LQ queue who is going to be able to edit the question" on SO, VLQ flags on questions only lead to triage, not to the LQ review queue.

Comment: @Braiam Actually.. as per my understand and some recent meta posts [My “Very Low Quality” flag got denied on a 'question' that wasn't actually a question on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402291/my-very-low-quality-flag-got-denied-on-a-question-that-wasnt-actually-a-que) and [(Yet another) why was my VLQ flag (very low quality) on a question declined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401352/yet-another-why-was-my-vlq-flag-very-low-quality-on-a-question-declined) they very often get picked up by moderators with the result of a declined flag.

Comment: @Scratte Read my comment again. I'm talking about a very specific queue.

Comment: @Braiam You mentioned Triage.. and the Low Quality Post queue. Which one is very specific? :D The *actual* very specific queue that is relevant here is one of the moderator queues, and you didn't mention that one.

Comment: @Scratte no I didn't. Read again. I mentioned something very specific, with a quote.

Comment: @Braiam It wasn't obvious that you meant to only look at the quote and disregard your mention of the Triage queue. But.. I just tried to say that Triage doesn't actually get it either, since it's often "intercepted" by a moderator. So neither queue gets the Question. You could say it's relevant that the Low Quality Posts queue doesn't ever get it under any circumstance, which is also true.

Comment: I did not know that the SO office had a cat.  What is it's name, and can we have a cute pic?

Comment: It's quite frustrating to have these sort of inconsistencies exist on the site. VLQ and closure are part of *the same dialog* for a lot of people and (these days) closure very misleadingly says "needs improvement", which is blatantly false for all the posts that should be closed but probably can't be fixed through editing or migration. If I didn't know all the context, I would very heavily lean toward flagging many or even most posts that should be closed as VLQ, which would unknowningly be "arguably an abuse of the system" that would result in many of those flags getting declined.

Comment: Should I flag as VLQ questions that are not *just* too broad, but *way* too broad to be reasonably edited into shape (I.e. unsalvageable)? ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74131901))

Answer (score 8):

**tl;dr if you cannot downvote or vote to close a question, *DO NOT* flag it as Very Low Quality. You are doing more harm than good!**

---

To paraphrase Cody's excellent answer: almost always... yet also never.

Almost always, because going on the dictionary definition of "very low quality", pretty much every question that should be closed is of very low quality.

Never, because the Stack Overflow definition of "very low quality" is "shove this question into Triage so somebody else can determine that yes, it should be deleted, oh and also badger a moderator because why not?". Of course that outcome is not explicitly documented anywhere, so people who can't downvote and are trying to be helpful just end up creating unnecessary work for both the poor sods who are trying to work the broken mess that is Triage, and of course our moderators.