# What is the current workflow for the Very Low Quality flag on questions?

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts

In [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357344/6471538) answer, Cody Gray mentions that the Very Low Quality (VLQ) flag for *questions* is used to "enqueue posts in Triage", but also mentions that they are handled differently by different mods.

What is the current workflow for VLQ flags on questions? Are they handled by mods? By the community? By either a mod or by the community depending on whether other factors are present? What is the workflow?

This question is not about what the VLQ question flag workflow *should be*, nor is it about whether or not we should [eliminate the VLQ flag for questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195673/it-shouldn-t-be-possible-to-flag-questions-as-very-low-quality), but an answer to this question could be valuable input for evaluating the future of the VLQ flag for questions.

Comment: Related: [Question flags, queues, edits, roomba, community♦, how does this actually work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300659)

Comment: @Gimby that is the answer I referenced in my question. If it answered my question, I would not have posted this one.

Comment: Now I feel a little more silly than I usually do. I wonder what kind of workflow you expect to find when everyone handles it differently.

Comment: @Gimby that answer mentions that different mods handle it differently, so perhaps it would be helpful to understand *when* a VLQ question flag goes before a mod. Do *all* VLQ flags on questions end up in a mod queue? Only VLQ flags on questions that have a score above 0? Only VLQ flags on posts that do not have any close votes? Only posts flagged during a full moon?

Comment: Honestly, I cannot answer this, because I don't really know all of the details of our overly-complicated review system. All I can point you to is the page from which the quote ("enqueue posts in Triage") was drawn, which includes a diagram showing how VLQ flags interact with review queues. I already included that link in my last answer. The only thing I could add to that is that posts in LQP review queue are shown to moderators after 1 hour, but we have lots of flags, so we don't necessarily handle them quickly, and that doesn't remove them from LQP.

Comment: So, yes, all posts flagged as VLQ will *eventually* end up being shown to mods, but might get handled by the community before that in some review queue or another, or might not actually get looked at by a mod. And then, different moderators handle things slightly differently when we *do* see them, as discussed at length in my last answer. I'm sorry if you feel that's inadequate or inconsistent. It is. I'd like to see the flag system changed, but I can't do it myself. I don't have dev access.