# In what universe is this an answer?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer, specific-answer

[Link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49109496/5958455) and [link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44106683/5958455)

The content of the answer reads

> “my_tests,SNR=533033200650344358002D00,TNR=test HelloWorld=123 1495179651177999872 \n SNR=533033200650344358002D00,TNR=test HelloWorld=444 1495179651203000064”

The difference from the first quote block in the question to the answer is shown as following (scroll right):

```
my_tests,SNR=533033200650344358002D00,TNR=test HelloWorld=123 1495179651177999872 my_tests,SNR=533033200650344358002D00,TNR=test HelloWorld=444 1495179651203000064
                                                                                  ---------
                                                                                  +++
my_tests,SNR=533033200650344358002D00,TNR=test HelloWorld=123 1495179651177999872 \n SNR=533033200650344358002D00,TNR=test HelloWorld=444 1495179651203000064
```

Although I am 100% innocent of the topic of the question (InfluxDB), I don't think I am too illiterate to understand such an "answer". So I flagged it as NAA and got that flag declined.

Can anyone tell me how on earth is it an answer, and why my flag is declined?

Comment: FWIW, please downvote it too, then. Flags can be declined (for whatever reason), but downvotes send a signal that can't really be disputed.

Comment: According to the answer's [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49109496/timeline), it was in the LQ review queue on Feb 7. The review is https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22138819 .

Comment: @S.L.Barth That should be my NAA flag

Comment: According to the oft repeated guidelines, it is an (extremely poor) attempt to answer. The usual spiel is: no need for mods to handle this, just use your votes. While it may be desirable getting rid of trash was slightly easier, I have to say that I do not understand the reluctance to use votes in these cases.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That is still an attempt at answering, so I declined the NAA flag.

The answer is stating that the lines should be delimited with `\n`, not `\r\n`. It's a terribly *bad* answer, as it doesn't state this explicitly, but it was an attempt at answering *nonetheless*.

I've deleted it now, because it took me yet another double-take to figure out why I had declined the flag last night. But note that the [other, much newer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54559973/100297) makes what the post you flagged tried to say much clearer as it calls out the line separator error and explains what is going on. But now that that post is there the first one is no longer needed.

Comment: In this case, would a "VLQ" flag have been accepted? (I'm a little on the fence: It's not gibberish, it's just a bad answer)

Comment: @Cerbrus: no, because it isn't gibberish.

Comment: @Cerbrus no, a bad answer is "low quality". *Very* Low Quality answers are things like "dood ur question sux", "aspe yes the +1 hyperdrive \n in Python for excellence in C; the matrix elegant", and answers not written in English.

Comment: Guys, MartijnPieters already answered the question adequately. It was a bit of a hypothetical _"What if this was flagged VLQ?"_. I wouldn't have flagged that.

Comment: @RobertColumbia But they're NAA :P, hence problem with VLQ, everything that is VLQ is covered by either NAA or R/A

Comment: If flag name is "very low quality" for answer I think it should be valid flag for very low quality answer (thing that is answer but quality is very low). Complete gibberish would be NAA or spam? Maybe rename flags?

Comment: @SampoSarrala: VLQ flags have a very specific meaning. It is *not* for 'I think this post is low quality'.

Comment: @SampoSarrala: [Am I misusing the "Very Low Quality" flag?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265764)

Comment: Yes flag description does make it a little bit more clear, it looks like VLQ is actually useless flag or maybe it is used to make it more clear that flagger don't think that it might be useful as comment and should not therefore be flagged as NAA. Bad flag name and overlaps too much with other flags. Get rid of NAA or replace with "should be comment"

Comment: "The answer is stating that the lines should be delimited" and **the answer was deleted, as it should be**. [The other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54559973/792066) is the one that actually states what the problem and solution is. That one is an answer to the question asked. The one that OP has in the question merely added some string without logical nexus to the question.

Comment: I confess to not understanding the purpose of VLQ flags, either. I interpret them with the emphasis on “very”, and see them as a “this needs to be deleted ASAP” request. This is consistent with Jeff Atwood’s original intention, something along the lines of, “this garbage is stinking up the place and needs to be removed as quickly as possible”. All other interpretations are just qualifications on this. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357344 @sam

Comment: Also...pretty sure I would have missed the attempt to answer that Martijn saw here. It looked like gibberish to me, and there’s an extremely good chance I would have just deleted. So, a completely understandable flag, and evidence that moderators are not robots.

Comment: Seriously, that was an attempt to answer the question? What did they answer exactly all I see is a ream of text, no explanation no attempt to answer the question. How you can justify declining a VLQ or Not an Answer flag in this instance is baffling to me, what is the point in the flags if not for instances like this?

Comment: @Lankymart: there were also comments on the question, I think the author wanted to document what the value was going to look like *in context of those earlier comments*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters still no explanation, just a bunch of post data isn't an answer by any stretch.

Comment: @Lankymart: it is still an *attempt* at answering. We have downvotes for 'this isn't anywhere near what we expect from good answers'.

Comment: @MartijnPieters if it's left there and it isn't flagged eventually some "tool" will upvote it, find it frustrating that those trying to keep the place tidy are the ones that get penalised.

Comment: In the future, if something has obvious quality problems but not enough to warrant deletion, please consider leaving a brief comment suggesting improvement when declining.

Comment: Why not *edit* the answer to make it clearer what the intent of the author was? It's basically the correct answer, just formatted/explained badly. A single line of text would clarify it.

Comment: To be honest, as it was written in the way I saw, I am completely unable to understand its intent to signify the importance of LF instead of CRLF - no text explanation and almost identical code, which just confuses people without adequate knowledge in the relevant field.

Comment: This answer demonstrates that VLQ and NAA flags shouldn't even exist.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: how come? How will we get rid of *Thanks, this question solved my porblem!* and *I still can't get this to work, can you fix this for me, here is my code:* and *oaaiaop,ai,aeaosuanue Ceci n'est pas une pipe* without those flags?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: put differently: start by understanding what those flags are for in the first place, and stop projecting what you *want* them to mean on them. Don't use them for attempts at actual answers, **however bad**.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But the answer was *still deleted by you*, even with the declined flag. So I am not sure what to understand

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: The NAA flag **doesn't apply**. I can still make a decision, as can any other member of our community with enough rep to have earned the privilege, to cast a delete vote for other reasons. In this case, I knew that that post was going to receive only downvotes, and there was a much better answer present, so I felt it was better for the answer to be deleted. We decline flags and then delete posts or comments for other reasons all the time.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I see, thanks for the replies

Comment: @MartijnPieters that’s the bit that is so frustrating, the outcome you agree is the answer warrants deletion but you also decide to decline the flag that brought it to your attention in the first place penalising the community member trying to maintain a degree of quality. You could argue all day what is or isn’t an answer, if someone writes something into the answer box they are attempting to answer the question. But if it doesn’t have some form explanation as an answer should than it ain’t a answer imo.

Comment: @Lankymart: the community always has the option to downvote, to maintain that level of quality. This example was on the extreme side of unclear, but that doesn't make it a good idea to have moderators judge the technical quality of every incorrect or unclear answer out there. NAA has a very, very clear definition, and it is working great for its purpose. Next, how much actual harm was that answer doing, to cause such a lot of upset? We have got better things to do with our time than debate this point endlessly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Point taken but it’s not an isolated incident is it, I just don’t think we should be penalised for trying to maintain quality.

Comment: @Lankymart: a single flag decline is hardly 'penalising'. There are no points attached to flagging, and it helps teach people to flag *better*. You speak of maintaining quality, giving feedback on correct flag use is *also* maintaining quality.