# Merge downvote and flag button together

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flags, downvotes

I have an idea: merging down-votes and flags together.

It is basically what it sounds like. A downvote is a flag. The amount of downvotes your post has is the amount of flags it has. Just like flags, this merge would allow for downvotes to be rejected. (i.e. duplicate "downvote" not a duplicate).

The OP would also be able to see the reasons for each of the "flagvotes"(that's what I'm going to call them).

The reason I came up with this idea is because I often see downvotes, but no reason for those downvotes. Some people had the idea for a reason to be given for downvotes(which I think isn't a bad idea), but I think merging the two would make things a lot simpler, as downvoting because *This question is unclear or not useful* also means that the question is supposively flag-worthy.

If you think this isn't a good idea, or think this could use some ironing out(obviously it does), then please let me know and why.

**P.S.** This isn't a duplicate. This is suggesting my unpopular opinion of two things being merged, not *just* **you must give reason for downvote**.

Comment: @DavisBroda This isn't a duplicate. This is suggesting that they be merged.

Comment: A downvote isn't a flag, and isn't meant to be.  Downvotes are to signal quality.  Flags denote something problematic that means additional action needs to happen to the post.  Not every downvoted post needs more action; it could just be plain wrong.

Comment: Flags and votes have distinct purposes. A flag is to indicate an potential issue with the post that needs to be looked at by reviewers and/or moderators. A vote indicate the usefulness of the post. Those are in no way connected.

Comment: Downvotes and flags are **entirely different things**. We certainly wouldn't want people to confuse the two things. Voting (up or down) is integral to the site, and normal behaviour that we encourage, no commenting is necessary nor will it ever be required. Flagging is for **exceptions to the norm**, where us moderators deal with the flags (the vlq and naa flags are first sent to a community review queue, but are ultimately handled by moderators too if the community doesn't complete review). Moderators will not and never will handle individual votes on posts.

Comment: My flag dialog doesn't state that. The down vote tooltip does.

Comment: You’re not going to get any rationale for downvotes. Downvotes aren’t for the OP, they’re for everyone else, so that they can easily get to the good stuff, and never see the bad stuff. You’re also not going to be able to reject downvotes. No one can reject your vote for president, and no one can reject your downvote. Please just internalize the way the system works. I promise you that you found SO in the first place because this system works so well.

Comment: @Vakore while downvotes and flags often go together, that doesn't mean that they are the same thing. It just means that they often have similar causes. For instance, an "answer" that contains gibberish is both flag-worthy (not an answer) and downvote worthy, as it is not useful. However consider a solution to some SQL question that actually solves the problem, but leaves the user open to SQL injection attacks. That is not flag-worthy, as it does provide an answer. But the vulnerability would justify a downvote.

Comment: The low quality flag is used for stuff that's gibberish. A post that's just, "WODIJ;ALKDJ la;lsdkfja;sdlkfj  ;aliwfja;dlfw;elk ;alkwejfapowdkfjawe;l ;alwkdnfa;lwdknadwfkl;ajo  SLSLSLSLSLS!" gets the low quality flag.

Comment: @Vakore: no, there is a flag for **Very** Low Quality. That flag is used when a post can't be salvaged, because it is basically gibberish. *ayau oyou flagging oopsie wha?* is worthy of a VLQ flag, because no one can be expected to make sense of it and can't be edited into something useful. That's very different from *voting*, which is used to rank content by usefulness.

Comment: @BSMP Then the flag should say its for giberish then.

Comment: Read VLQ as "moderator, this needs to be deleted immediately", and you won't have a problem.

Comment: @CodyGray Also, if it was gibberish, that would fall under **Spam**.

Comment: It is a rather useless flag. Nobody knows what it means. I'd love to eliminate it, combine it with something else, or reword it, but I don't have the power to do any of those things. If you have time to kill, see [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357338/when-is-a-closeable-question-a-very-low-quality-question/357344#357344) for more information. And no, spam is not gibberish. Spam is unsolicited promotion. But you could argue that gibberish is "rude/abusive".

Comment: No, spam is for undisclosed self promotion.  That's not at *all* the same thing as gibberish.

Comment: @Vakore: "*This is suggesting my unpopular opinion of two things being merged, not you must give reason for downvote.*" But you explicitly state that you want the merge to happen to get people to give a reason for voting.

Comment: That's not the definition of spam used by the site/Stack Exchange network. Here, a post has to at least be promotional to be considered spam (and has to either be undisclosed or done too often for it to be a real problem).

Comment: @Vakore Ok, removing that motivation and say we merge the two categories, by adding a flag that has the same content as the current downvote tooltip: what do we gain? What other motivations do you have besides explaining and being able to contest downvotes?

Comment: @BSMP Ok then. Would be nice if some flag options were merged as well.

Comment: @Vakore: "*I also think that a new user with a good question not knowing what is(or isn't) wrong with their question is very daunting.*" But the flag doesn't change anything; it's just a generic statement, equivalent to what is on the tooltip. The user doesn't even find out that their question has been flagged in that way, because that's not how flags work. So how does this help?

Comment: @Vakore Ok, so that’s two things. Let’s take them in reverse: the second one is still just “explaining downvotes”, which you’ve been told isn’t going to happen (and as you’ll find in the dupe and its other inbound Qs, has been discussed ad nauseum). The first is just confusion on your end, and from the unanimous comments here and the general success of the site, doesn’t seem to hold back others. The cure there is just to learn the difference between flagging and voting. Plenty of material here on Meta for that.

Comment: I’ve downvoted this question and did not flag it.

Comment: @Vakore I rarely flag, and most of my small number of flags are on answers that don’t answer the question, or spam. But I vote constantly, and I have more downvotes than upvotes. If you’re flagging and voting together newly every time, you’re in a small minority.

Comment: @Vakore No, I didn’t flag it. I did downvote. And when you say “exactly”, you realize I’m saying I do the exact opposite of what you do?  As I said, I rarely flag and downvote. And flags are typically for non-answers, not on questions.  Note also that Meta is different than main, downvotes here also indicate “I understand this suggestion but I don’t want it implemented”.

Comment: @Vakore That is the opposite of what you just told me. And with only 13 votes, you might consider you don’t have enough experience to suggest sweeping changes.

Comment: @DanBron 1) was talking to yivi(notice the @), 2) There are a ton of questions that need flagging on SO. And if you think the question isn't useful, then I don't see why that should be a flag reason itself.

Comment: @yivi I would delete this question as it is **clearly** not of any use, however I can't.

Comment: I wouldn’t say it’s if no use. It helps you and other visitors better understand how the site options are meant to be used. Peace.

Comment: You should not be vandalizing your own question.

Comment: The reason I closed this as a duplicate is because your main motivation for turning votes into flags is to make downvotes reasons visible, and shows some fundamental misunderstandings about what downvotes are for. The other post gives clear explanations about why we won't be changing how downvoting works.

Answer (score 12):

When you vote you are expressing your opinion about a post usefulness and quality.

By flagging you are signaling there are problems that make the post unfit for a site. **You do not flag a post because it's not useful, or because you believe it's wrong**. You use your votes for that.

Those two things are orthogonal and should not be merged.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't make sense to merge flags and down votes because:

- There is no a flag for a question not being useful (or not showing research effort, the other reason in the tooltip).
- Going the other way, it isn't necessarily the case that you would down vote everything that you flag. It is possible for a duplicate to be a good sign post.
- It doesn't make sense to reject votes because votes are subjective. We are allowed to disagree on the usefulness of a post.

> I've never seen something downvoted under 5 votes but not flagged.

One reason a post might get down voted but not flagged is the question asker is trying to do something which is a terrible idea. Much like DavisBroda's suggestion of an answer that has security flaws, a question that asks how to do something that will break something else, make it unsecure, make maintenance impossible, etc. may get down votes.

Another reason might be that the asker knows a solution to their problem and not only won't use it but refuses to explain why (or their reason is terrible).

There's no close reason for "bad idea" but many people don't consider questions that ask how to do things the wrong way or how to do something in a way other than the obvious, easy way to be useful.

Comment: 1) I think there should be a flag for that. 2) Ok, dups I can understand, but perhaps that could be its own thing. 3) You're probably right, though I stand by my idea.