# Please remove Very low quality type flag on questions

Tags: feature-request, questions, flags, low-quality-posts

I have found  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61026628/unable-to-perform-some-functions-after-i-hosted-my-webpage-in-000webhost) today, which was a total gibberish. In my opinion it was not even worth casting 3 close votes, because it is just a waste of 3 people's votes and time. I cast a VLQ flag on it. My flag got declined, probably because this was not worth mod's attention and time either.

This means that this flag type is completely useless. You can't use it to flag gibberish, because it will be declined. If it is spam or rude then we have red-flags. If the question is not answerable we have close votes/flags.

The VLQ flag on **questions** is just confusing and should be removed. It is confusing and redundant for answers too, but it works. Mods and most users treat it the same as NAA, but with a chance for OP to salvage it (a benefit of a doubt, e.g. they pressed submit to quickly).

**Could we block or remove the Very Low Quality flag type from questions?**

Comment: @gnat No, it does not, because I already know I am misusing it. Everyone is misusing this flag type, because nobody has a slightest idea of what is its purpose.

Comment: Perhaps you should read [Guidelines for reviewing low-quality posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180029/267099)?

Comment: "Gibberish, or posts in the wrong language: If the post is clearly not intended to be understandable, or is not written in English or the language of the site, recommend deletion or closure as Needs detail or clarity."

Comment: @DavidPostill I appreciate the post you linked, it is very useful, but my proposal is not about reviews in LQP. I simply want to remove the obsolete flag for questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It is a moderator roulette game. Not all of us would have declined your flag on that gibberish question. Related: [When is a *closeable* question a *very low quality* question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357338/when-is-a-closeable-question-a-very-low-quality-question)

Comment: @CodyGray True, but that means that the flag has no clearly defined meaning, which only proves my point it is confusing and should be removed. It could have been improved and some guidance provided by Stack Overflow, but people have complained about its ambiguous meaning for long and the situation is still the same, which is why I propose to remove it altogether.

Comment: Yeah. You'll notice I arrived at the same conclusion in that long, rambling answer I linked you to above. :-) Although, nowadays, I think I'm leaning more towards merging NAA and VLQ into a single, "needs to be deleted" or "unsalvageable" flag, rather than just removing VLQ.

Comment: @CodyGray True for answers, but there is no NAA for questions.

Comment: The ongoing confusion related to this flag is evidence that it needs to be removed. My recent "very low quality" flag on this question got declined, and I struggle to think of a more perfect example of what _should_ be flagged as VLQ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61086610/how-do-i-model-a-solution-to-rosenbrocks-parabolic-valley-in-c

Comment: @Sean Actually, your example should just be closed. It can be saved if provided more details. VLQ should, in theory, be used for stuff which can't be edited into shape even by OP and should be removed quickly. I do agree it is confusing and the meaning is not well defined.

Comment: @Dharman The description text for "Should be closed" and "VLQ" _both_ note that the question is unlikely to be salvaged via editing. If you believe it can be saved with more detail, then it seems neither of those should apply.

Comment: @RobertColumbia No, it doesn't.

Comment: I've had almost all of my VLQ flags declined so far because every user has a different understanding of what "very low quality" means. So I'm not using that flag anymore since it probably won't get through anyways and it became completely useless to me.