# (Yet another) why was my VLQ flag (very low quality) on a question declined

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, low-quality-posts

Don't use this flag very often, but I thought that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63968174/if-a-pop-up-alert-physical-repeats-itself-is-there-a-defence-mechanism-we-should was just basically nonsense:

[image]

I thought the VLQ was designed to flag questions like this, but then found my flag was declined... *declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it*

I know there are other questions explaining things like this and from the answer to [Am I misusing the "Very Low Quality" flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265573/am-i-misusing-the-very-low-quality-flag) the answer seems to be *Use VLQ for obvious, unarguable garbage.* and the question (IMHO) epitomises that.

Comment: I think this is your goto post: [When is a *closeable* question a *very low quality* question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357338/when-is-a-closeable-question-a-very-low-quality-question). But.. you have close votes. Why are you using the "Very Low Quality" flag for posts that are just closable where you can cast a vote? I agree that the Question in question is *very* unclear, but it doesn't need to be removed ASAP.

Comment: @Scratte, I voted to close it 3 hours ago and as you see it's still not closed.  As for not clear, could you explain what the question is?

Comment: I've been told I can read gibberish, so I'll have a go at it: They've noticed that upon certain events, they can create an event handler ("unearthed a command"), that notifies them upon said event with pop-ups. However, they want to know if there's anything else they can do, as the eventhandler only gives them a message about the event. When they say "a common expectation, currency or curfew", I think it's a botched Google translation and they mean to say "expected result within a deadline". The last sentence seems to me to be about not disturbing the normal flow of the program.

Comment: @Scratte or it's written by a bot

Comment: @RobertLongson That is also a possibility. I suppose I'll add "Possibly able to read bots" on my resumé :)

Comment: It looks like nonsense to me. I would have thought the flag was appropriate. If we shouldn't flag nonsense because it wastes mods' time, why do we have the VLQ flag at all?

Comment: Why are you raising a flag? To get the question closed. So... why not just _raise a close flag instead_, and cut out the moderator middle-man?

Comment: @IanKemp how do you raise a close flag? I've just taken a look at the Flag menu on a random stackoverflow question and I cant seem to find it.

Comment: @Flame Anything in the "needs improvement" are close flags. They reworked the dialogs and the wordings. It used to be "should be closed..." with ellipses clearly showing that it opens up another dialog. "A community-specific reason" also opens up a new dialog and so does "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network". You can play with the dialog as long as you do **not** push the big blue "Flag question" button :)

Comment: It sounds like the kind of nonsense spewn by [Stack Roboflow](https://stackroboflow.com/highlights/index.html).

Comment: @Scratte Impressive!

Comment: @scratte That was better than Gandalf reading the runes on the Doors of Durin.

Comment: Yikes, this really does look like the work of a robot. Imagine if a legion of those bots start flooding the site with this kind of ScrattlePrattle. Can we overcome that?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I would say it's probable they just missed how bad this question was at a glace. Speaking from experience, the console sometimes helps you slip into a rhythm and you see a lot of other posts mixed in. It could be there were a series of needed declines and this looked like the others. As is usually the case, hindsight is 20/20 and moderators are human.

As to how to avoid it, you're a [Trusted User](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) so you have three tools at your disposal

1. Vote to Close
2. Downvote
3. Vote to Delete [(quickly)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)

Even if you're not a Trusted user, there are flags for closure. Closing is the fastest way to get this handled; three votes and you're done. As Arghya mentioned, [there's a chat room (SOCVR) dedicated to helping with that](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).

## Some clarity on VLQ questions

I seem to have muddied the waters with some people and in mulling this over, I realized I should probably make things clearer. VLQ in general is marked helpful when the post is edited or deleted. Questions also add closure to that list. I'm going to call these Low Quality Questions, or LQQ, so we don't confuse them with VLQ *answers*

In general, when you want action against a question you have several flags at your disposal

1. Spam/Rude (red flags) - Six of these makes Community delete them (and the poster takes a -100 reputation hit). And Mods pay special attention to them when they're open. Also usable on [pure gibberish nonsense](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035/244695)
2. Closure (confusingly called Needs Improvement in the flag dialog) - This throws the question into the Close Queue. Three Close votes will close it
3. VLQ - There's a narrow band between red flags and moderator flags, where the question is obviously terrible, but it's not red flag worthy
4. Moderator flags - Tell us what's wrong

The problem with LQQ is that the VLQ flags are often *misused* by new users who don't know any better. As such, moderators are likely to deal with the answers first, and then cursory scan the remaining LQQ. If it's not clear what's wrong with the question **it's likely to be declined**, especially if you need someone familiar with the subject.

Closure is a much clearer path in almost all cases, and SOCVR is an excellent place to get help if you think something needs closure immediately. The irony of VLQ is that your flag might not be reviewed for hours or days, when the community could have closed it in short order.

Comment: Interesting to note that a Moderator should 'forewarn' the audience when they're about to *be honest*. That would *almost* imply that it is *not* the default behaviour! ‎

Comment: Seems like removing it from UI would make sense. What is point of providing users with an option that is virtually useless and wastes mod time?

Comment: @charlietfl Or, leave the option in the UI but, when a user selects it, produce a harsh popup saying, "Please do not use this type of flag!" A bit like [this](https://www.flickr.com/photos/85295287@N08/8444802125/).

Comment: @AdrianMole Honestly I've thought of suggesting the UI omit it for questions entirely, but I suspect there are some reasons it can't be. We need to make closure clearer in those cases

Comment: I use it on sites where I can't cast a close vote.

Comment: @Joshua And you've illustrated why mods dislike this flag. If you can raise a VLQ flag, you can also raise a flag to close the question (meaning it goes into the close queue for privileged users to review it). VLQ means that you want a moderator to close/delete it. Most of the time, you really want the former

Comment: What is your answer to the OP's literal question in the subject, then: "Why was my flag declined?" Are you saying that moderators don't like the flag's existence and thus always decline it?

Comment: As you can see (mostly) in the image, I did all of 1, 2 & 3.  Just out of interest - what do you think might satisfy the VLQ flag criteria on a question?

Comment: @JörgWMittag It's not that we don't like it, it's more that there's better flags for it in most cases and we get a metric ton of flags (in the last week alone we had about 7000 flags handled). What you're saying with VLQ question flags is you want a moderator to review the question and close it, when the community has a system to do the same thing. So, no, a moderator isn't going to spend a ton of time on them. If it's not blatantly obvious it's highly likely to be declined

Comment: @NigelRen Where the question is obvious nonsense. For instance, a question about how many clowns fit into a car would stand out and probably get closed by by most mods because it sticks out like a sore thumb. Anything that needs us to evaluate the quality of the question (beyond a simple processing it's something of a question) is almost always getting declined because we literally have more flags to handle

Comment: Any question that is obvious nonsense can be closed without mod involvement. (If it is actually offensive then there are other types of flag for that.) So the VLQ flag is utterly pointless for questions then. If that is the case, that should be the official guidance.

Comment: If VLQ on a question is never accepted then why is VLQ flag on a question an option in the first place?

Comment: @matt One word: [Triage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322590/244695)

Comment: @Machavity That's what's very confusing. Why does that diagram show that a Question flagged as VLQ goes to Triage, when it then turns out that a moderator declines the flag? Anyone reading that post will assume the post **only** goes to Triage.

Comment: The biggest argument for VLQ on questions is probably that too few people are willing to use "abusive" flags (and, I suppose, some moderators too reluctant to validate them).

Comment: @Shog9 That argument just lost all it's meaning, no? Anyone that reads this post will be even less likely to use it. At least with a red flag there's a chance the flag will get disputed, not declined.

Comment: IIRC, a majority of flags are raised by folks who might read this @scratte - but a majority of people raising flags will not read this.

Comment: Perhaps there needs to be some other discussion about IF there should be a VLQ option, personally I will just avoid it in the future (unless clowns are mentioned ;).  I do appreciate what moderators do (I did vote for you, so I'm partially to blame for putting you in this position), but for the meantime I think it's probably better to finish my quest for an answer.

Comment: @Machavity - *"Where the question is obvious nonsense."* The quoted question **is** obvious nonsense. It couldn't be much more obvious. :-) I get that the main thrust here is "use your other tools, don't add Yet Another Flag to the moderator queue" and I get that part (I never use VLQ on questions), but again: Why was the flag **declined** on what was obviously, at a glance, a VLQ question?

Comment: _“If it's not blatantly obvious it's highly likely to be declined”_ – But isn’t declining a VLQ flag effectively saying “I’ve actually reviewed this and found the post not to be of low quality”? Shouldn’t a different outcome be chosen then; the only remainder being disputed? Ideally, there should be an option “didn’t bother looking, so please solve otherwise or re-raise a flag if you really think that it’s a pressing issue that cannot be solved using other means”.

Comment: @poke We have a decline message for that: "Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see [What is Flagging?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)"  Remember, VLQ comes with no context. We have to be able to guess what it was you were thinking. When in doubt, raising a mod flag will allow you to provide the context. Of course, they're slower as well and half the benefit of VLQ is speed.

Comment: "I'm not even sure that .001% use case exists" This is the supposed use case: [**"catching awful questions that slipped through the cracks somehow. We'll see how that works out in practice..."**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244736/213575), but when you read the last bit and the fact that communication with moderators didn't happen.... well...

Comment: Oh, hey, the horse mouth is here too. So, I'm quoting @shog , and well, what happened with documenting to moderators the expected usage? Or was all implied?

Comment: VLQ flag* is a waste of time in all* cases

Comment: @Machavity I just want to let you know that this answer makes absolutely no sense to me. If I use letters to represent the various positions: the OP claimed `A` is true. This claim was declined. In your answer, it's like you're saying "most of the time it's pointless to point out that `A` is true, and anyway, `B`, `C`, and `D` are true also. It seems like it's irrelevant what other things are true, and if you don't care about `A`, then it shouldn't be available as an option.

Comment: I don't understand why stack overflow don't appoint enough moderators to deal with all the flags

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The mod who declined the flag is kinda busy, but I would say it's probable they just missed how bad this question was at a glace. Speaking from experience, the console sometimes helps you slip into a rhythm and you see a lot of other posts mixed in. It could be there were a series of needed declines and this looked like the others. As is usually the case, hindsight is 20/20 and moderators are human.

Comment: @GregSchmit I mulled it over a bit last night and made some clarifying edits. I hope I didn't muddy the waters too much initially

Comment: @Machavity Very informative post. In order to actually answer the question, I think it's missing a line at the top saying "It was probably declined by mistake and here's why that might happen:"

Comment: @Machavity - Yeah, we've all done that. You're clicking through X repetitive task and you misclick and ... :-)

Comment: @rdans I wonder if there are actually enough qualified people!

Answer (score 0):

> Why was my VLQ flag on a question declined?

Moderators just have quite a solid and defensive posture when handling such borderline posts which *potentially* could be edited to shape and the question's intention moreover seems to be on-topic (note that the description of the problem is unbelievable bad but it however attempts to describe a problem AFAICS).

Also note that moderators do not need to be subject matter experts and do not judge the correctness of the things stated inside of a post. So to determine whether it really is off-topic or not is not a task for them.

Instead, It should be closed by community members who understand the relative topics as "Needs details or clarity", "Needs debugging details" or "Needs more focus".

It doesn't necessarily need moderator intervention and the moderator does not judge the context's quality. These are the reasons why such flags tend more to get declined than accepted (although however bad quality).

Just cast a vote to close/delete the question and omit flagging if moderator intervention is not 100% necessary.

Comment: "So to determine whether it really is off-topic or not is not a task for them" this was their jam at the start of SO. Then the flags were offloaded totally to the community.