# My "Very Low Quality" flag got denied on a 'question' that wasn't actually a question on SO

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

[Link to the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64463463/c-sharp-google-api-v3-upload-speed-is-10-18-mbp-s-but-when-do-upload-through-g)

I got a VLQ flag denied on a SO post that wasn't even a question, just someone stating that the Google API for c# is slow. I was wondering if anyone could explain why that flag was denied since the moderator didn't send any explanation to me. I just see `declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support`. I got access to the review queues today and this is the only flag/unsalvageable that has been denied.

Comment: In addition to flagging as VLQ when you can vote/flag to close... I don't think there is any queue where flagging as VLQ is appropriate... VLQ *sends* questions to one of the queues, should not really be used to move post between queues...

Comment: What do you mean by `flag to close`? I've never seen anything like that in any of the flagging options

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts 4 (Needs improvement) and 5 (duplicate) are "flag to close", which turn into "vote to close" options after 3k rep.

Comment: Thanks for looking out for the quality of posts on this site! We do appreciate your efforts. Sorry for the annoyance of this edge-case. **For questions that don't fit our guidelines and need to be closed, please flag as "needs improvement", instead of "very low quality".**