# Multiple flags on questions with screenshot declined

Tags: support

I found some questions where the code in in screenshot and flag them as *very low quality*. Flags on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63988832/how-to-get-the-dynamic-height-and-width-of-a-particular-div-of-html-using-angula) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64155247/i-tried-code1-which-works-well-but-when-i-put-data-data-sort-in-code2-sh) question are declined.

[image]
[image]

Why? Are questions actually need to only include one screenshot of the code?

Comment: Flagging question as very low quality is rarely a good idea. Better vote or flag to close the question. Related: [When is a closeable question also a “very low quality” question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357338/when-is-a-closeable-question-also-a-very-low-quality-question). The triage review that invalidate those flags was nevertheless totally wrong.

Comment: Also relevant: [(Yet another) why was my VLQ flag (very low quality) on a question declined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401352/yet-another-why-was-my-vlq-flag-very-low-quality-on-a-question-declined) and [My “Very Low Quality” flag got denied on a 'question' that wasn't actually a question on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402291/my-very-low-quality-flag-got-denied-on-a-question-that-wasnt-actually-a-que)

Comment: Basically click on "flag" → "needs improvement" (these are the close flags) → pick one or go further into "A community-specific reason". For these post with images "Needs details or clarity" is a good choice :) @BDL I do not think Triage can "decline" a flag. I think that was a moderator. I think Triage can only "dispute" flags.