# What would have been the correct flag for this low-quality code dump?

Tags: support, questions, flags, declined-flags, low-quality-posts

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64685748/need-help-android-building) as "very low quality" because the question had no effort, just posting the error message.

But this flag was declined. I don't know what other flag I should have used. It is certainly not spam and it isn't off-topic either.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It most certainly is off-topic. As you said yourself, it's just a code dump. There's no question. [In order to be on-topic for Stack Overflow, questions need to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

**The correct flag would have been "needs improvement" → "Needs debugging details".** This will raise a flag on your behalf, indicating that the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Regarding the "very low quality" flag... well, I won't bother to [repeat myself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357338/when-is-a-closeable-question-also-a-very-low-quality-question/357344#357344). All I can say is that I would have validated that flag, were I to have been the moderator who processed it, but I know that other moderators see things differently. Now, you know, too. Hopefully, some day, no one will need to know that, because there won't be a useless, confusing flag like "very low quality".

Comment: Hopefully, some day, we will be able to punch lazy users like that in the face over the Internet.

Comment: To be honest I think closing, deleting and ghosting is more than enough. I can't see Internet punches as being anything more than another tool to be weaponized by trolls.