# I flagged a question as "very low quality", the flag review was "declined", but the question was closed due to lack of clarity

Tags: discussion

I recently reviewed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67655067/can-a-selenium-whatsapp-bot-can-run-in-simultaneously-groups), and I noticed my flag was " declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it." I went to the link for the post, found above, and discovered that the status is "Closed. This question needs details or clarity. It is not currently accepting answers."

My question -- How can my flag be counted as "declined", given the question was closed? Is there some insight available into this that I am missing?

Comment: See [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265764/8967612), but also [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357344/8967612) too.

Comment: TL;DR: This is a problem with the VLQ flags and it has always been. It's almost never clear-cut. I personally try to avoid it at all times.

Comment: OK... so, if  "VLQ" is not the ideal way to indicate these questions should be closed, what is? A downvote and a comment?

Comment: VLQ flags don't have a defined usage, to be honest. If a question is closable you may want to go with a closure flag instead of VLQ. You can flag to close a question and it will go into the close queue for 3k users to judge whether or not it should be closed.

Comment: @C.Peck In If the question is unclear, then downvote and Flag > needs improvement > Needs details or clarity. If it's off-topic, then Flag > needs improvement (which [doesn't make sense](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351279/348196)) > A community-specific reason > then pick the appropriate reason.

Comment: Doesn't directly address your question, but relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160754/why-are-the-moderators-being-so-strict-with-quality-related-flags-recently

Comment: "*How can my flag be counted as "declined", given the question was closed?*" as a general rule, VLQ would apply *at least* if no closure reason applies. "Needs details or clarity" is an existing closure reason and seems appropriate for the post.