Reason for declined "Very Low quality" flags
I recently flagged several questions as VLQ.
Some of them were found "Helpful" while others were declined with following message (with my emphasis):

Declined - Questions should never be flagged as "very low quality". Other flags are always more appropriate. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357344

I found it very confusing.  So we have a legitimate flag that should never be used. Then why to have it at all?
And while it should never be used, some usage is nevertheless accepted as Helpful.
Please note that my question is strictly about the decline reason and not about the quality of the questions I actually flagged.

Because moderators are not developers and therefore don't control the UI, they just have to work with it and they have requested this flag be removed. Also there's more than one moderator and we don't force them all to agree with each other on every possible question. All this is explained in the link so why are you asking again?

'Very low quality' flags on questions are marked helpful automatically when: the post is closed for any reason, any edit happens to the post, or the post is deleted for any reason. It's likely the majority of your helpful flags were marked so automatically due to these systematic factors.

"Then why to have it at all?" - or an alternative question: why is it not removed? Answer: because improving the site is at a very low priority. The way it is now is pretty much how it is going to stay until the summer of AI love happens.
